# missing data in Firebase / Google analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

We accidentally unlinked our Google analytics account from Firebase and linked it to another project in another organisation.

Status quo is that in current project we do have new data from the time we proceeded the unlinking and in the old project we have old data before the time we did the unlinking. Is there any way how to merge those projects to have all data in one place ?

Answer (score 0):

Your analytics data resides within Google Analytics property and not in the Firebase project. If you delete or unlink the property, then your data is unlinked from your project as well. BQ integration is disabled during this period and sometimes the exporting apps are not getting enabled after relinking.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).